# how to check if app is running on android tv or android phone?

Tags: android

I am working on an universal app for Android TV and Android phone,
Is there any way we can programmatically check if app is running on android TV or android phone ?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6767330/995926).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking if the device has a touch screen:

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.touchscreen");
```

Note however, that this is not guaranteed to work on all devices, as some manufactures don't implement it correctly in their ROMs.