# How can I check if an app is running on an Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

Is there a way to check if an app is running on an Android TV or Android  Mobile?

I know how to check the running build. I want to start a specific service if the app is running on an Android TV vs Mobile. Was hoping to house the two under the same library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some options are:

1) Query the system for a large screen

2) Use reflection to detect TV specific classes

3) Use [hasSystemFeature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) to detect the lack of touchscreen

More info

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html

And a similar answer for Google TV

[Identify GoogleTv from Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209204/identify-googletv-from-android-app)

Comment: The Android Team recommended check for androidTV this way https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html

Comment: For whatever reason, the recommendations by the Android Team did not work for me. Testing for the lack of a touchscreen, as suggested by Robert, was successful.

Answer (score 46):

From [Handling TV Hardware](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html) in Android Docs:

```java
public static final String TAG = "DeviceTypeRuntimeCheck";

    UiModeManager uiModeManager = (UiModeManager) getSystemService(UI_MODE_SERVICE);
    if (uiModeManager.getCurrentModeType() == Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Running on a TV Device");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Running on a non-TV Device");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what Google mentions.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol getCurrentModeType. I got this error. thanks

Comment: There are missing semicolon at the end of both statements. thanks

Comment: This is the recommended way to do it from the Android training docs and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Some TV devices cannot access the UI_MODE_SERVICE (it comes null), so checking as well for system features like FEATURE_TELEVISION or FEATURE_LEANBACK as @Beloo suggested can be a good alternative for those cases.

Answer (score 24):

```
private boolean isDirectToTV() {
  return(getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEVISION)
      || getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK));
}
```

This will return `true` if the device is advertising itself as having either the `android.hardware.type.television` or `android.software.leanback` system features. Android TV and Fire TV handle this correctly; I have not tried it on other environment as yet.

Comment: +1 this approach lets you easily plug in features on the corresponding platform, I just used it for the Now Playing Card on AndroidTV.

Comment: FEATURE_TELEVISION is deprecated in API 21 and beyon. thanks

Comment: @MindRoasterMir: If your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, you could skip the `FEATURE_TELEVISION`/`android.hardware.type.television` parts and just use `FEATURE_LEANBACK`/`android.software.leanback`.

Answer (score 4):

Summarizing the previous answers:

- If `uiModeManager.currentModeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION` that's definitely a TV
- We can't rely on `currentModeType` to say that it is a TV, because some TV devices are actually return `UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL`
- So we should check `FEATURE_TELEVISION` for pre-lollipop and `FEATURE_LEANBACK` for lollipop devices.
- if you want to support not only tv's, but stationary devices with screen, you may add additional checks to predict it
- you should be careful with that to not show tv ui on the phone

This is a kotlin code we actually use:

```
enum class UiModeType {
    NORMAL,
    DESK,
    CAR,
    TV,
    APPLIANCE,
    WATCH,
    VR
}

private val modeType: Int
    get() = uiModeManager.currentModeType

fun getUiModeType(): UiModeType = when {
    modeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_APPLIANCE -> UiModeType.APPLIANCE
    modeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR -> UiModeType.CAR
    modeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_DESK -> UiModeType.DESK
    modeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_TELEVISION -> UiModeType.TV

    sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH &&
        modeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_WATCH -> UiModeType.WATCH

    sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O &&
        modeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_VR_HEADSET -> UiModeType.VR

    isLikelyTelevision() -> UiModeType.TV

    modeType == UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL -> UiModeType.NORMAL
    else -> UiModeType.NORMAL
}

private fun isLikelyTelevision(): Boolean = with(packageManager) {
    return@with when {
        sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP &&
            hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LEANBACK) -> true
        sdkInt < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP &&
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEVISION) -> true
        isBatteryAbsent() &&
            hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_USB_HOST) &&
            hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_ETHERNET) &&
            !hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN)
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private fun isBatteryAbsent(): Boolean {
    return if (sdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        batteryManager?.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY) == 0
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```