# How to distinguish if Android app runs on Smartphone/Tablet or Android-TV-Stick?

Tags: android, android-tv, android-package-managers

I applied [following to distinguish between normal Android OS and Android TV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6767330/14564029):

```
if (pm.hasSystemFeature("com.google.android.tv")) {
    // here it is a Android TV
} else {
    // here it is a smartphone or tablet or Car
}
```

It does not work for Android based TV sticks. I think it works for GoogleTv only?

**How can I check for any Android based TV?**

Comment: There is nothing in the framework that allows you to know what type of system the app is running on let alone just a TV that has Android as the OS, thats still technically just Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We match by `android.software.leanback` OR `com.google.android.tv.installed`. Where the former is the "official" way to check for it but of course manufacturers always do their own thing.

The latter was chosen by checking out quite a few different devices and we haven't had any complaints about not supporting TV hardware after that.

---

To publish to the PlayStore with `<uses-feature ...>` in the manifest, we resorted to publishing two variants, each with one of the features as a requirement...